# System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break() has issues breaking in standalone DLL in PowerShell

Tags: debugging, c#-4.0, dll

I build a "hello World" kind of app-dll combination in C# and set the break point 
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break() in the DLL and it breaks promptly no issues. 
I have another exe and DLL combination for which I have the source code for the DLL only. In this new DLL source code I insert System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break() build the **Debug** version of the DLL but when it runs in a PowerShell it does NOT break. Why is it not breaking? Further System.Console.WriteLine() works in my sample DLL but not in the real DLL. 
I checked the csproj file hoping to find a setting like Break on BreakPoint: NO or Screen Print: NO or something to that affect no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was loading the DLL inside a PowerShell and then running it and hoping it to freeze up or show some sing of failure. Then after much Googling I realized PS was preventing the break and the display. So the solution is, run WinDbg and open powershell.exe (Open executables). That will open a new PS and in that environment my DLL does break and does display the Console Writes.